# Can we combat questions on meta that should be somewhere else?

Tags: discussion, meta, off-topic

It might just be me, but I believe Meta is experiencing a rise in the amount of questions that should be asked on other Stack Exchange sites.  These are the ones I could find just from the last 24 hours, there were probably more:

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103530/job-and-studies [10k only]
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103504/problem-with-back-key-in-activity-group-in-android
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103506/postfix-on-ubuntu

I can understand this problem existing on Stack Overflow, where a question about Apple, Ubuntu or Wordpress might end up and be off topic (I.e. no programming elements). I can also understand the questions on Meta that should be on Stack Overflow, since if you're not clear on what the word `meta` means and you ignore every other piece of text, it's not a hard mistake to make.  However, of the three questions linked above, one should have been asked on Ubuntu.

Is Meta starting to see a rise in these questions and, if so, is there something we can do beyond flagging them as off topic?

Other questions related to, or generated because of, the problem of off-topic posts:

- [What could be done to stop off-topic questions on Meta from polluting the tag base?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53553/what-could-be-done-to-stop-off-topic-questions-on-meta-from-polluting-the-tag-bas)

Comment: Sorry, but the job and studies question isn't really on topic for Programmers - if nothing else it's too localised. Also the "Why can't I ask a question on Stack Overflow?" **is** on topic for meta. It just happens to be a duplicate.

Comment: Fair enough, I thought programming career/education advise was on topic for Programmers? Obviously, that was a bad question anywhere, but what I meant was that it should have at least been attempted (and closed/deleted) there, rather than here.

Comment: We've had to update our [FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq) because of the many bad and non programmer specific career questions we were getting.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100607/more-explicit-message-on-the-ask-question-screen and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103230/what-can-we-do-to-prevent-people-from-posting-their-coding-questions-on-meta

Comment: @ChrisF, I have removed the Account question - no idea how that crept in there (and then missed my pre-post proof read). Also removed the reference to Programmers and read the updated FAQ, it had been some time since I'd read it.

Comment: @jonsca, not sure how I missed that second one, posted 3 days ago... This one is more broad, since I want to stop all off-topic questions from becoming endemic on Meta, no matter the benefits to my flag weight.

Comment: @static They are similar, I think.  I was including them more for completeness and as evidence of the problem you describe.

Answer (score 2):

They already are combated. Downvotes, voting to close, and migrating takes care of the combating part well. If you don't like how this is handled and have an idea to improve it, such as in the [related questions posted by @jonsca in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103532/162637), that would be a better question.